# Finding vertical and horizontal components of objects result force

Tags: physics, classical-mechanics

I have the question "Resolve the forces acting on the following objects into their vertical and horizontal components and thus find the vertical and horizontal components of their resultant force.

[image]

The solutions say that the answer should be:

[image]

And I know that I have to use trigonometry but I am not sure how the answer is achieved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extend the vertical line in the top figure might help.

The vertical upward force can be computed by

$$3-4 \cos(180 ^\circ-125^\circ)$$

The horizontal force towards the left can be computed by

$$4-4 \sin(180^\circ - 125 ^\circ)$$